# How do I get href links from href using python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to get href links which is present in href(which i have already) So I need to hit that href links and collect the other href. I tried but from that code only first href are getting, want to hit that one and collect href which present in that previous one. so how could I do that.
I Tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#soup.prettify()
#table = soup.find("table")
#print(table)
links = []
for href in soup.find_all(class_='omrlist'):
    #print(href)
    links.append(href.find('a').get('href'))
print(links)
```

Comment: you will either need to run a loop use scrapy/crawling framework for iteratively traversing links

Comment: can you explain how I use it here.I didn't use it before

Comment: Can you explain more your question? It looks that links already have all the href hat you need.

Comment: Using above code i got the href's but if you copy and paste in browser then there is all months links(href's) and again if you click month name then on next page there is link name 'Download full report'. so want to download that all pdf's from 'Download full report' link and store in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here how to loop to get report url

```
import requests

root_url = 'https://www.iea.org'

def getLinks(url):
    all_links = []
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    for href in soup.find_all(class_='omrlist'):
        all_links.append(root_url + href.find('a').get('href'))  # add prefix 'http://....'
    return all_links

yearLinks = getLinks(root_url + '/oilmarketreport/reports/')

# get report URL
reportLinks = []
for url in yearLinks:
    links = getLinks(url)
    reportLinks.extend(links)

print(reportLinks)
for url in reportLinks:
    if '.pdf' in url:
        url = url.replace('../../..', '')
        # do download pdf file
        ....
    else:
        # do extract pdf url from html and download it
        ....
    ....
```

now you can loop `reportLinks` to get pdf url

Comment: with ypour code I got these.--['https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2018/0118/',  'https://www.iea.org/oilmarketreport/reports/2007/1207/',./../../media/omrreports/fullissues/2018-10-12.pdf', .........'https://www.iea.org../../../media/omrreports/fullissues/2018-06-13.pdf', 'https://www.iea.org../../../media/omrreports/fullissues/2018-01-19.pdf', 'https://www.iea.org../../../media/omrreports/ass/AnnualStatisticalSupplement_201But I want 'https://www.iea.org../../../media/omrreports/fullissues/1990-01-01.pdf' till 2018 and want to download that pdf and store in DB. So How could I do it.

Comment: it should get report link from 1990, try save `reportLinks` to file and see if all url extracted.

Comment: Yes got it all .pdf file links but that links is not working coz in that link extra dot '.' is adding so how i overcome from it. I got "https://www.iea.org./media/omrreports/fullissues/1998-03-10.pdf" But I want "https://www.iea.org/media/omrreports/fullissues/2018-03-15.pdf"

Comment: can you please give answer of my 2nd question

Comment: store the file to DB?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296491/how-do-i-download-pdf-file-from-links-present-in-veriable

Comment: @ ewwink, this code is giving me prob while putting in class So, can you please tell me how i put this code in class.(prob in yearLinks variable)